# Correct setenv.sh settings for verbose garbage collection with Tomcat Apache 9

Tags: tomcat, jvm

I am running Tomcat 9.0.34 and want to make sure I have the correct settings for verbose garbage collection.

There are many answers for Tomcat 8.0 and earlier but not many for 9+.

Here is what I have for it. I have this in my setenv.sh It seems to work but just want to make sure I am not missing anything. Not sure about the file settings either. hoping to also get heap info out of this.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -verbosegc -Xlog:gc=debug:file=$CATALINA_HOME/logs/gc.log:time,uptime,level,tags:filecount=5,filesize=100m"
```

Comment: Please don't include "thanks" or similar in your question. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions, and here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I believe that technically you should use `-verbose:gc` instead of `-verbosegc`, but experimenting on my local java9 install suggests both work.